# How to change brightness for single view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm a newbie in programming for iphone. I would like to ask how to change screen brightness for single view (controller). I'm currently using this.

```
- (void) loadView
{
    [super loadView];

    userBrightness = [[UIScreen mainScreen] brightness];
    [[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness: 1.0];
}

- (void) viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];

    [[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness: userBrightness];
}
```

But I can't use 'viewDidUnload' method because it is deprecated. I don't know how to return the previous value of the backlight when I switch to another view or terminate app. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing brightness on when the view loads is too persistent, even if your view is offscreen, the brightness won't change back to normal levels. Remember the concept of changing the screen brightness is a global action, and is not aware of the context it's changed in (in your case, applying for when a single view is on screen). I'd suggest reading the documentation on the [particulars of the view lifecycle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html).

You could consider using `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear`, which will provide the granularity you need.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to use `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear` methods instead of `loadView` and `viewDidUnload` but it does not work if I hide / terminate app.

Comment: In that case, you'll need your view controller to monitor notifications when the app will be hidden/dismissed, as well as coming back to focus. This will act as if the view controller was disappearing and appearing. Subscribe to the `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` and `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` notifications, using `NSNotificationCenter`

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't upvote. It's require 15+ reputation :(.

Comment: You can accept the answer though, this will increase your rep. Simply select the tick on the left hand side of the answer :)